# should be a socket closed ALWAYS if read() or send() returns <0?

Tags: sockets, winsock

Unless read() or send() returns <0 with WSA_IO_PENDING or WSAEWORLDBLOCK, is there any case of read() or send() returns <0 but the connection is STILL alive?

I wrote my code which ALWAYS close connection if read() or send() returns <0 except for WSA_IO_PENDING or WSAEWORLDBLOCK, but I am not sure whether I am on right track.

Please reply. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That sounds just about 100% correct to me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, on Unix there's at least one other [`errno(3)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/errno.3.html) value that doesn't mean end of the world - `EINTR`, see for example this from [`send(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/errno.3.html) manual:

`EINTR  A signal occurred before any data was transmitted; see signal(7).`